# Finding Intervals a and b, integration

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tw8Rq.png

I'm not entirely sure how to do this or what it's asking me to do.

Comment: Like making up an equation then integrating it and solving the definite integral? How does that help me?

Comment: Okay, so taking f(x)=x and solving the integral and subtracting them I get 20. So now, I'm at trying to find two numbers (intervals) that when I plug them into the integral of x the answer is 20?

Comment: Well for integration. What you do is integrate x which becomes (x^2)/2 and then put the lower and upper bound limits into the equation. Therefore (11^2)/2-(5^2)/2) = 48. What can I do knowing another bound which is c=9?

Comment: Alright so integration of sinx = -cosx. -cos(11)+cos(5) is what I get.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by that. Are you saying you want me to do (-cos(11)+cos(5))-(-cos(9)+cos(5))?

Comment: Oh I see, so cos(5) cancels out, therefore a=9 and b=11. Wow thanks so much I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Will do, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Solved it due to someone else here. The answer is a = 9 b = 11